# FFMPEG avcodec_find_decoder(2) (CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) always returns incomplete AVCodec?

Tags: c#, c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I got a problem with FFMPEG (avcodec-54.dll)
1) I wrote a .NET wrapper. As far as I can see it works well.
2) I try to decode something... and thats were the problem is:

```
...
  FFmpeg.avcodec_register_all();

  pAVCodec = FFmpeg.avcodec_find_decoder(CodecID.CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO); //which is in int 2
  Console.WriteLine("CodecID " + (*pAVCodec).id);
  Console.WriteLine("CodecType " + (*pAVCodec).type);
  Console.WriteLine("CodecName " + (*pAVCodec).name);
....
```

---

No EXC was thrown and the following output came:

```
CodecID CODEC_ID_NONE
CodecType 1790854254
CodecName mpeg2video
```

---

What confuses me the most is that the name is correct, but the id and type are wrong.
In the previous Version if the DLL everything works fine. This behaviour came up with the new version.
Any guesses or debugging tips?